# How do I write the HTML BODY String of an array of items without key to an FORM POST action?

Tags: java, android, html, arrays, post

I have this specification:

```
FirstName = "Steve"
LastName = "Jobs"
 PhoneNumber = "3334445555"
 PhoneNumber = "4445556666"
 PhoneNumber = "7778889999"
```

and I need to POST to a Server, from an `Android` app written in `Java`.

The problem is the Array has no name (ie. no key). There can **unlimited** number of items (ie. phone numbers).

My client wants me to send it as a `HTML Form POST`. I can construct a BODY String like this `"firstname=Steve&lastname=Jobs&...`HOW DO I PUT THE PHONE NUMBERS HERE?"

How do I post the array?

Further, my client says the server side API connection (receiving form post) is not developed yet.

I'd like to how to construct the `POST` Body String (and how to advise my client to program the server side to receive it).

Note: My client does not want `JSON` form.

*Sounds like this is a strange requirement from my client, any creative suggestion?*

Answer (score 0):

## Index

You can add an index in the parameters `phone1`, `phone2`, ...
The server will need to check if those exists. It might requires to catch an exception but this would be OK.

An alternative to this issue would be to add a `phoneCount` parameters, that way, you know how many phone number to recover.

`"firstname=Steve&lastname=Jobs&phoneCount=2&phone1=3334445555&phone2=4445556666`

On the server side, you just have to do some like

```
int phoneCount = param.getInt("phoneCount");
String[] phones = new String[i];
for(int i = 0; < i phoneCount; i++){
     phones[i] = param.getString("phone" + i);
}
```

NB: this is not a working code, this doesn't use any "known" library, this is a just a logic to use.

## Concatenate

You can also concatenate every phone number like `3334445555|4445556666`
On the server-side, you just have to split the value to get an array of phone numbers.

```
String[] phones = param.getString("phones").split("|");
```